# Getting a user's organization repositories in the GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

We are using the GitHub API on Stack Overflow Careers to bring in a user's repositories. We haven't succeeded in bringing in a user's repositories that are part of an *organization*.

For example, wycats is a contributor to the jQuery project. Yet [querying his repositories](https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/wycats) via the API does not indicate this -- the [jQuery repo](https://github.com/jquery) is owned by the [jQuery organization](https://github.com/jquery).

What is the API call(s) to learn that wycats is a contributor to the jQuery repository? The correct answer will take the form of a URL(s) which returns a list of organization repositories for a given user name. If it takes more than one call, that's fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for.

> #### [Checking Organization Membership](http://develop.github.com/p/orgs.html)
>
> ```
> /user/show/:user/organizations [GET]
> ```

https://github.com/api/v2/json/user/show/wycats/organizations

> #### List all public repositories of any organization
>
> ```
> /organizations/:org/public_repositories [GET]
> ```

https://github.com/api/v2/json/organizations/jquery/public_repositories

Comment: This is pretty much what you're after.  You're right that the org "owns" the repo.  There really is no context for the "organization repositories for a given user name" ... the org has repos, the org also has users.  Beyond that it's just a matter of what permissions the user has, which is not available from the public API as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance - I've got no experience using the GitHub API, but I _can_ read API docs.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to do better than what the docs offered. There is a /organizations/repositories route which promises to do what I was looking for, but it errors out for me.

Comment: @Matt I think the problem with that route is that it only shows organizations that "you can access" (whatever that means) and there's no way to specify a user other than yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [github api](http://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/) with authentication. I got errors without retrieving a token first. Here is the working code (just use your own organization and username :-) )

```
organization="write-here-the-organization"
githubuser="your-github-user"
token=`curl -i -u ${githubuser}  -d '{"scopes": ["repo"]}' https://api.github.com/authorizations | grep token | cut -d\" -f 4`
curl -i -H "Authorization: token ${token}" https://api.github.com/orgs/${organization}/repos
```

as result of the above you will get a long json with all repositories, and their information. you can continue from here.

in my case I wanted only the ssh paths so I will clone all of them in a loop, so I did

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token ${token}" https://api.github.com/orgs/${organization}/repos | grep "ssh_url" | cut -d\" -f 4
```